# Copy one file to different, differently named folders

Tags: cp

I have a need to copy one file from /a/b/ folder to /a/c/, a/d/, a/e/

Besides using

cp file.name /a/c
cp file.name /a/d
cp file.name /a/e

in the terminal, is there a way to use one line? I have read and seen that thera are ways, but I think my situation is different as my destination folder names are different.

I also want to ask that is it possible to cp a file into a destination folder and one recursive level in. So if there is a folder that has a/b/c/d, and you drop it in a, it goes to b and b/c, and not b/c/d.

Comment: I understand the responses perspectives, so let me clarify.
The environment is as such:
One terminal is connecting to 5 different servers. Each server has the same file structure (they are copies of one another like nodes), but for the destination folders for the file.
So I am using parallel-ssh to connect, so you can understand the perspective of using one command line, but can cater for all 5 different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's bad because **`cp can copy multiple sources but cannot copy to multiple destinations`** which is what you need. For this to work you have invoke cp multiple times - once per destination which you have already tried. What you want can be accomplished by

#### 1. Using for loop

```
for i in /a/c/ a/d/ a/e/; do cp "$file" "$i"; done
```

This is pretty mush self-explained.

#### 2. combining `cp` with `xargs` :

```
$ echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp file1
```

Will copy file1 to dir1, dir2, and dir3.  xargs will call cp 3 times to do this. `xargs` will invoke `cp` 3 times and copy file1 to dir1, dir2 and dir3 in successive calls.

In your case it will be

```
$ echo /a/c/ a/d/ a/e/ | xargs -n 1 cp /a/b/file
```

For further details about xargs, see [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a cheat, but you could redirect the content of the file to multiple destinations using `tee`:

```
tee a/{b..d}/file.name < file.name > /dev/null
```

Comment: this would work if a/{wildcard}/file.name - as an example